# Skip an element in the loop using the trycatch function

Tags: r, rvest

I have a list of websites that I would like to scrape, fe

```
review_links <- c("https://www.filmtotaal.nl/recensie/12882", "https://www.filmtotaal.nl/r")
```

On the links I would like to perform the following function:

```
read_txt <- function(a_review_link){
  read_html(review_link)
  txt <- pg %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="text"]//text()') %>% 
  html_text %>% trimws %>% 
  grep('^[a-zA-Z]+:|\\|$|^[0-9]*$', ., 
   invert = TRUE, value = TRUE) %>% 
  paste(collapse = ' ')
}
```

However when I loop over the list with the function like:

```
for(review_link in review_links){
  read_txt(review_link
}
```

I get an error. Therefore I am experimenting now with some error handling. However when I do this:

```
for(review_link in review_links){
  tryCatch(read_txt(test_error), error=function(e) return ("No valid URL"))
}
```

I do do get the output I expect (the second link should pop up an error). Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: `pg <- read_html(a_review_link)`? And pasting error messages is usually quite helpful.

Comment: Your loop isn't storing objects into anything. You have to create an output object, in this case probably a list.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the documentation for tryCatch and this is what I came up with.  It is the first time I have used tryCatch.

```
review_links <- c("https://www.filmtotaal.nl/recensie/12882", "https://www.filmtotaal.nl/r")
read_txt <- function(a_review_link){ 
  tryCatch( pg <- read_html(a_review_link),  error = function(e) e, {
    txt <-      
      pg %>%    
        html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="text"]//text()')  %>%    
        html_text %>%    
        trimws %>%     
        grep('^[a-zA-Z]+:|\\|$|^[0-9]*$', .,invert = TRUE, value = TRUE) %>%     
        paste(collapse = ' ')       
  })  
}  
for(review_link in review_links){
  print(read_txt(review_link))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs correctly on my R:

```
library(rvest)

review_links <- c("https://www.filmtotaal.nl/recensie/12882",
                  "https://www.filmtotaal.nl/recensie/12883")
read_txt <- function(a_review_link) {
  pg <- read_html(review_link)
  txt <- pg %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="text"]//text()') %>% 
  html_text %>% trimws %>% 
  grep('^[a-zA-Z]+:|\\|$|^[0-9]*$', ., invert = TRUE, value = TRUE) %>% 
  paste(collapse = ' ')
}

lst <- vector(length(review_links), mode="list")
k <- 1
for(review_link in review_links) {
  lst[[k]] <- read_txt(review_links)
  k <- k+1
}

lst[[1]]
# [1] "Cast : Het Hongaarse lichtabsurdistische liefdesdrama On Body and Soul sleepte ...

lst[[2]]
# [1] "Cast : Janet heeft er hard voor geknokt, maar nu het gelukt is mag ze het ...
```